# How to call hooks inside custom hooks ? Getting this error => Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, expo

---

This is my App.js file code.
I am trying to make custom Hooks as [per official documentation  link](https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks#:%7E:text=Although%20there%20is%20no%20such%20built%2Din%20Hook%2C%20you%20can%20write%20it%20yourself.%20Declare%20a%20function%20called%20useOnlineStatus%20and%20move%20all%20the%20duplicated%20code%20into%20it%20from%20the%20components%20you%20wrote%20earlier%3A). Here they have used useState inside custom hook, but I am not able to do so. Please point out the issue so I can solve this. I had tried multiple times.

I have read the article https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning and tried solving it. But why cannot I use hooks inside hooks, I cant understand.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from "react-native";

const useFirst = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState();
    console.log("My Name");
};

function useSecond() {
    const [name123, setName123] = useState();
}

export default function App() {
    const name = "Hello";

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Brand New Expo App</Text>
            <Button title="First" onPress={useFirst} />
            <Button title="Second" onPress={useSecond} />
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        backgroundColor: "antiquewhite",
    },
});
```

[image: Error]

[image: Dependencies]

[image: React Tree]

Comment: Is there a reason that you need to create new state on every button press? React doesnt allow for calling hooks outside of the top level of a component/hook; but even if you could, you would just be creating new state on every button press

Comment: Thanks @PhantomSpooks, however as per official documentation [link](https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks#:~:text=Although%20there%20is%20no%20such%20built%2Din%20Hook%2C%20you%20can%20write%20it%20yourself.%20Declare%20a%20function%20called%20useOnlineStatus%20and%20move%20all%20the%20duplicated%20code%20into%20it%20from%20the%20components%20you%20wrote%20earlier%3A), I have some similar situation.
I need to use useState in my custom Hook that I am trying to make.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there are problems in these functions.

```
const useFirst = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState();
    console.log("My Name");
};

function useSecond() {
    const [name123, setName123] = useState();
}
```

It is not possible to use react hooks in the member functions.

`const [name, setName] = useState();`

`const [name123, setName123] = useState();`

As well, I think they have no meaning in those functions.

You can get an idea by running this.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [name123, setName123] = useState('');
    const GREETING = "Hello";

    const useFirst = (name) => {
        const greetings = `${GREETING}, ${name}`;
        setName(greetings);
        console.log(greetings);
    };

    function useSecond(name) {
        const greetings = `${GREETING}, ${name}`;
        setName123(greetings);
        console.log(greetings);
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Brand New Expo App</Text>
            <Button title="First" onClick={() => useFirst("My Name")} />
            <Button title="Second" onClick={() => useSecond("My Second Name")} />
            <Text>{name || ''}</Text>
            <Text>{name123 || ''}</Text>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        backgroundColor: "antiquewhite",
    },
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Alan, I completely understand your code, but I am trying to learn custom hooks as per [link](https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks#:~:text=Although%20there%20is%20no%20such%20built%2Din%20Hook%2C%20you%20can%20write%20it%20yourself.%20Declare%20a%20function%20called%20useOnlineStatus%20and%20move%20all%20the%20duplicated%20code%20into%20it%20from%20the%20components%20you%20wrote%20earlier%3A)official docs, that's why I was trying to use useState inside my hook

Comment: Your custom hooks are valid (except they essentially do nothing since they dont return a value), its just that you are calling them in the wrong place. They have to be called in the outer most scope of the component or hook they are being called in. You have to use work arounds to get hooks to do stuff on button presses. For an example, `useState` cant be used in `onPress`, but it does return a setter function that you can call in `onPress`

Comment: If you look at the AssetExample component [here](https://snack.expo.dev/uL6u_CXgU), I create a custom hook for animating color changes; and provide buttons for changing colors.  I achieve this by having the custom hook return a function that will update its internal state

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using a hook in an `onPress` callback. Hooks can only be called at the top level of a component/hook. From what I can tell you have two different names and you want to set `name` to these values on button presses. You may not even need to use a custom hook to achieve this:
But if all you are doing is fetching a name, it may not even be necessary to create a separate hook to do so:

```js
export default function App() {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const fetchName1 = async ()=>{
       const data = await fetch("http://url1.com/")
       const json = await data.json()
       setName(json.name)
    }
    const fetchName2 = async ()=>{
      const data = await fetch("http://url2.com/")
      const json = await data.json()
      setName(json.name)
    }
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Brand New Expo App</Text>
            <Button title="First" onPress={fetchName1} />
            <Button title="Second" onPress={fetchName2} />
        </View>
    );
}
```

In the above example, on every press, a fetch to some api is made. To avoid making unnecessary api calls,  you could give each name its own state and on mount fetch and set that state. To avoid cluttering App.js, then create your own hook:

```js
const useFirst = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    
    useEffect(()=>{
      const fetchData = async ()=>{
          const data = await fetch("http://url1.com/")
          const json = await data.json()
          setName(json.name)    
      }
      fetchData()
    },[])
    return name
};

function useSecond() {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    
    useEffect(()=>{
      const fetchData = async ()=>{
          const data = await fetch("http://url2.com/")
          const json = await data.json()
          setName(json.name)    
      }
      fetchData()
    },[])
    return name
}
```

Now you call these hooks in App.js, and on button presses, set name to their values:

```js
export default function App() {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const name1 = useFirst();
    const name2 = useSecond();

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Brand New Expo App</Text>
            <Button title="First" onPress={()=>setName(name1)} />
            <Button title="Second" onPress={()=>setName(name2)} />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Phantom, I completely understand your code, but I am trying to learn custom hooks as per official docs [link](https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks#:~:text=Although%20there%20is%20no%20such%20built%2Din%20Hook%2C%20you%20can%20write%20it%20yourself.%20Declare%20a%20function%20called%20useOnlineStatus%20and%20move%20all%20the%20duplicated%20code%20into%20it%20from%20the%20components%20you%20wrote%20earlier%3A), that's why I was trying to use useState inside my hook.

Comment: The end part of the answer contains a hook based approach. I'll create an expo snack with more examples of customs hooks, althought most of them will be in typescript

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/1ZbumUjYm

Comment: I think creating custom hooks become easier if you think of them as a normal react components that returns variables instead of JSX

Answer (score 0):

This is what I actually trying to work. Added useState / hooks in custom Hook.
Special Thanks to @PhantomSpooks.

This code worked for me.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

const useFirst = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  // Anything Needed to perform
  return name;
};

export default function App() {
  const firstName = useFirst();

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{firstName}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "antiquewhite",
  },
});
```